# Ada: Writing output numbers in a file separated by a tab

Tags: tabs, formatting, ada

Just putting part of some code here where I am writing two values to a **text** file.

```
Ada.Long_Float_Text_IO.Put (File => Output_File, Item => Out_2, Fore => 1, Aft => 4, Exp => 0);
Ada.Text_IO.Put (Output_File, "   ");
Ada.Long_Float_Text_IO.Put (File => Output_File, Item => Out_3, Fore => 1, Aft => 4, Exp => 0);
```

I can separate these numbers `Out_2` and `Out_3` by a *space* as shown in the code. The results give (after writing more numbers in the two columns):

```
-75.2340   421.5700   
1256.0000   15.4700   
-4568.9800   -118.2800   
3784.2100   0.0000
```

I would like to know if there is a way to specify a *tab* spacing so that I can have something like this in my **text** file:

```
-75.2340     421.5700   
1256.0000    15.4700   
-4568.9800   -118.2800   
3784.2100    0.0000
```

So which control character produces the above alignment?

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a tab, there’s the obsolescent `ASCII.HT` or `Ada.Characters.Latin_1.HT`.

Or you could use the `Width` parameter to `Ada.Long_Float_Text_IO.Put` and friends.

Edit: There is no `Width` parameter for real output! You could use a large `Fore`, which would effectively right-justify the output.

Comment: @ Simon Wright Yes *width* works only for integers and enumeration types.

Comment: @ Simon Wright Your solution with the use of `width` seems better as we can have *alignment* with the decimal place as well.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of that intervening:

```
Ada.Text_IO.Put (Output_File, "   ");
```

Call the [Set_Col](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-A-10-1.html#I5728) procedure instead, which moves the output line position to the specified column. E.g.

```
Ada.Text_IO.Set_Col(Output_File, 13);
```

Comment: @ Marc C Thanks. I just need to find a convenient value for the column number. 1 vote up.